# How to pass parameter to child uiView in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state with multiple views.

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']).state('property', {
    url: '/property',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partial/propertyView.html',
            controller: 'PropertyController as property'
        },
        'queue@property' : {
            templateUrl: 'partial/queueView.html',
            controller: 'QueueController as queueController'
        }
    }
})
```

propertyView.html

```
<input type='text' ng-model='property.filterCode' ng-change='property.search()'>

<div ui-view="queue"></div>
```

how to pass filterCode variable to queueController?

Comment: you could launch an event when the code changes, you could move the data filtering code into a service, you could have a parent controller in an abstract state

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe use a directive? Depending on your app structure I find that nested views have a tendency to become quite hard to manage. Also directive is a perfect fit for this!

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.queue = "1"
});
```

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="queue">
<queue queue="queue"></queue>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('queue', function($) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            queue: '=queue'
        },
        template: '<div>{{queue}}</div>',
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            // Do whatever you want with it
            console.log(scope.queue);
        }
    };
});
```